# Is it necessary to read Anne Rice's Vampire Chronicles in order?

Tags: suggested-order, vampire-chronicles

I want to read Anne Rice's Vampire Chronicles, but I was told I shouldn't read the first one. I was told that the second one is better. So, do you have to read them in order, or are they separate stories?

Comment: Anne wrote the first one not really expecting to write a bunch of sequels, as I recall... As a result, a lot of details had to be retconned in the next book, which she did by making them simply told from the perspective of the main character (Louis) in the first book, and disputed by Lestat in the subsequent books.  I still favor reading them in order, myself.

Comment: The story won't make as much sense if you read the books out of order.  The first book is by far the best one, and it sets the stage for everything that follows.

Answer (score 3):

No its not necessary to read the books in chronological order, but easier because certain books actually happen BEFORE others.  However, Anne Rice herself somewhat cancels the first book out by having Lestat refer to Louis as a liar and say in the second book that most of what Louis says is misinformation due to his lack of telepathic ability or lies and his account is the true account and what he says is the Real truth...only the happiness and love they shared was true.

Answer (score 1):

All I can say is read them in order. If you omit one I hire *Interview with the Vampire* I would say. I started *Queen of the Damned* twice. Once, it took like 12 pages to describe one kill. Though that’s cool, I was like”get on with the story”. Second was two Xmas’ ago. I was given a first edition (w/sleeve) in mint condition. When my girlfriend told me how little she had paid ($3-4), I figured ‘damn. Whoever sold it didn’t know what they had. Once I get the paperback I’ll read it. As far as skipping books in a series. Not a good idea. If you read them out of order, I’d read *Interview with the Vampire* before *The Tale of the Body Thief*.
I’m reading *Witching Hour* now, so I’m not very in touch with Lestat stories at the moment.